# Possible causes for "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out" under high load?

Tags: java, connection, timeout, nio

I'm having this "java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out" exception with my clients when they're connecting to a server.

They're all in the same LAN, in the same cluster, with no firewall between them. Also, they work just fine up to 1000 clients, more or less. When I launch 1200 clients, many of them (a couple hundreds) timeout when connecting to the server. Each clients keeps sending requests to the server, which impose cpu load on the server, which is about 100% in a couple threads.

How can I avoid this problem, without adding servers nor increasing the timeout? I've also done `sudo sysctl -w net.core.somaxconn=2048`, to no avail.

I'm using NIO to connect to the server:

```
SocketChannel serverChannel = SocketChannel.open();
serverChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(serverAddr, serverPort));
serverObjectOutStream = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(serverChannel));
serverObjectInStream  = new ObjectInputStream (Channels.newInputStream (serverChannel));
```

As for the server:

```
while (running) {
   SocketChannel newClientChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
   ObjectInput  cliInput  = new ObjectInputStream (Channels.newInputStream (newClientChannel));
   ObjectOutput cliOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(newClientChannel));
   // receive client's id and put it in a hashtable of id -> in,out channels
   // acknowledge the client
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the server can handle 1200 concurrent clients?

Answer (score 0):

Check the network load.  Is your NIC topped at 100% usage with all those clients?  Also, the CPU at 100% can be a bottleneck.  Check this out.  You don't give much details, but also check if you OS need to be tweaked.

If you rule out hardware, it's time to check software.

Basically, what you have is the C10K problem.
Here is a really good read about it (with link to more reads)
http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the cause was that the server was not accepting new connections fast enought, since it handled each one of them, to only after accept the next connection.

That's how I finally solved it, so that the server could do stuff while still accepting new clients, preventing timeouts for them:

```
BlockingQueue acceptedConnections = new LinkedBlockingQueue<SocketChannel>();

// Thread 1 (connection acceptor):
public void run() {
   while (running) {         
      SocketChannel newClientChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
      acceptedConnections.add(newClientChannel);         
   }
}

// Thread 2 (connection handler):
public void run() {
   while (running) {               
      SocketChannel newConn = acceptedConnections.take();
      // handle new connection, while still accepting others
   }
}
```